# How commit multiple SQL statements in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

How commit multiple SQL statements in Oracle?
I tried to do like this :

```
BEGIN

TRUNCATE TABLE test;
        

ALTER TABLE test 
    ADD (a1 VARCHAR2(10),
        a2 VARCHAR2(2),
        a3 VARCHAR(2));
        
END;    
COMMIT;
```

But I have got an error:

```
    ORA-06550: line 3, column 10:
    PLS-00103: The character "TABLE" was encountered while one of the following was expected:    
:= . ( @ % ;
```

I wanted to use it like I always do in Postgres:

```
begin;
SQL1;
SQL2;
SQL3;
commit;
```

Comment: If you want to do DDL in an anonymous PL/SQL block, you'd need to use dynamic SQL.  `execute immediate `truncate table test';`.  DDL statements in Oracle always issue an implicit commit before and after the statement is executed so there is no need to commit a DDL statement and no way to roll one back.  For both of these reasons, it generally doesn't make sense to package multiple DDL statements into an anonymous block like this.

Comment: @JustinCave So, I dont need to commit them, but how can execute both statements from one file at once? I always get an error `ORA-03291: invalid option truncation - missing STORAGE keyword`. But when I execute them one by one there is no error

Comment: You can have as many SQL statements in a script file as you'd like and any client tool will happily execute them one after another.  The error you're getting doesn't make sense for the statement you're showing.  Can you post a reproducible test case that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can not execute the DDL statement in the PLSQL block.

Second, you don't need to commit to DDL statements.
An implicit commit is executed before and after the DDL statement.

If you want to execute DDL statement in PLSQL block then use dynamic SQL

```
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE test';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE test ADD (a1 VARCHAR2(10),a2 VARCHAR2(2), a3 VARCHAR(2))';
        
END;
```

Then your DDL will be executed in SQL Context.